# OpenMP thread managing in for loops

Tags: c, multithreading, optimization, concurrency, openmp

I'm attempting to optimise the use of thread in a complex for loop with OpenMP. The basic code looks like this:

```c
for (...) //loop1
{
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp single
    {
      //section that needs to be executed only once
    }

    #pragma omp for
    {
      for (...) //loop2
      {
        ...
      }
    }

    #pragma omp single
    {
      //section that needs to be executed only once
    }

    #pragma omp for
    {
      for (...) //loop3
      {
        ...
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

My problem is about thread creation/destruction as this code implies that every iteration creates and destroys N threads. Is there a way to tell the runtime to reuse the same threads (something like a thread pool) or is this something left to the implementation?

I need to pay attention to these constraints:

- The content of *loop1* can (and needs to) be made concurrent as it contatains some quite heavy scientific computations
- Iterations of *loop1* must be ordered, so the loop itself can't be made parallel

**EDIT**
Each iteration of loop1 must be executed only **once** (so I can't make the whole loop parallel

Comment: I don't think the situation with thread creation and destruction has changed materially since I commented on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353086/avoid-thread-creation-overhead-in-open-mp There is a variety of other Qs and As on the topic on SO too, some research would stand you in good stead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, threads will not be created/destroyed at each loop1 iteration. Usually there is a thread wait policy which you can control using the `OMP_WAITY_POLICY` environment variable:

https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse55.html#x294-20640006.7

In addition, there is nothing (at least in your pseudo-code) preventing to wrap all the code in a single parallel region. The code could perfectly be:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (...) //loop1
{
  #pragma omp single
  {
    //section that needs to be executed only once
  }

  #pragma omp for
  for (...) //loop2
  {
    ...
  }

  #pragma omp single
  {
    //section that needs to be executed only once
  }

  #pragma omp for
  for (...) //loop3
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Implicit barriers, at the end of each worksharing construct (ie, first single, loop2, second single, and loope), will guaranttee the order between iterations. In the case those barriers were no needed, you can avoid them using the `nowait` clause.

Comment: Nothing in the specification states that threads will not be created/destroyed at each loop1 iteration (it is rather the opposite). So a runtime could theorically create threads periodically, although libGOMP of GCC and libOMP of Clang/ICC do not in practice.

Comment: Note, too, that the rules about the preservation of thread static variables mean that creating and destroying threads arbitrarily may be difficult...